# What is the recommended pattern for extend html class in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I have following `<tr>` tag in my table

```
<% if user.company.nil? %>
  <tr class="error">
<% else %>
  <tr>
<% end %>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
</tr>
```

I would like to add another if statement

```
<% if user.disabled? %>
  <tr class="disabled">
<% end %>
```

So when two of this statements are `true` I would like to receive:

```
<tr class="error disabled">
```

I know I should move that to helper but how to write good case statment for extending class depends of this statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try a helper method, something like

```
def user_table_row(user)
  css = ""
  css = "#{css} error" if user.company.nil?
  css = "#{css} disabled" if user.disabled?

  content_tag :tr, class: css
end
```

not sure how well this will work in the case of a table row, as you will want to nest td inside it

**UPDATE:** here is updated version yielding the block of td code

```
def user_table_row(user)
  css = # derive css, using string or array join style

  options = {}
  options[:class] = css if css.length > 0

  content_tag :tr, options do
    yield
  end
end
```

then in the view

```
<%= user_table_row(user) do %>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def tr_classes(user)
  classes = []
  classes << "error" if user.company.nil?
  classes << "disabled" if user.disabled?
  if classes.any?
    " class=\"#{classes.join(" ")}\""
  end
end

<tr<%= tr_classes(user) %>>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
</tr>
```

But the good style is:

```
def tr_classes(user)
  classes = []
  classes << "error" if user.company.nil?
  classes << "disabled" if user.disabled?
  if classes.any?   # method return nil unless
    classes.join(" ")
  end
end

<%= content_tag :tr, :class => tr_classes(user) do -%> # if tr_classes.nil? blank <tr>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: 'content_tag :tr' gives tag with closing: <tr></tr>

Comment: Looks cool but hmm, I dont like this ``[].tap`` syntax :) But for now best option, thanks

Comment: avoid .tap if you don't like it)